# Require relative path in "client-side" JS in electron

Tags: node.js, electron, require

How does `require` work in Electron for scripts that are executed by `<script>` tags in HTML files?  For example, I have:

```
-index.html
-langs/js.js
-langs/test.js
```

I have `<script src="langs/js.js"></script>` in index.html and I want to require langs/test.js from langs/js.js, but this doesn't work:

`require("./test");`

It has to be `require("./langs/test");` even though the relative path from js to test is just "./test".  Is there a way to make it work without specifying the full path from the HTML file in every `require`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use `require` to load CommonJS modules, if you don't then Node won't be able to set up the module scope correctly and things will break in subtle ways. If you load `js.js` with `<script>require('./langs/js.js')</script>` then `require('./test')` will work as you expect.